# is there any way to maintain/get original content-type of file while passing through multipart/form-data

Tags: python, rest, lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

Im passing file and its name in multipart/form-data in postman to aws rest api in post call and uploading that file to s3 from lambda. But will get uploaded file in
binary/octet-stream type. So i want the original content-type/file type of file to store on s3. For ex if i upload file directly to s3 then i get
application/pdf format. is there any way to store files in its original type.

Below code im using :

```
post_data = base64.b64decode(event["body"])

if "Content-Type" in event["headers"]:
    content_type = event["headers"]["Content-Type"]
    ct = "Content-Type: " + content_type + "\n"
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(ct.encode() + post_data)

    if msg.is_multipart():
        multipart_content = {}

        for part in msg.get_payload():
            multipart_content[part.get_param('name', header='content-disposition')] = part.get_payload(decode=True)

        file_name = json.loads(multipart_content["Metadata"])["filename"]
        s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket="einvoice-attachments", Key=file_name, Body=multipart_content["file"])
```